# How to remove white grid from Mapbox mapView on Android?

Tags: android, mapbox

Is there a way to remove/disable white grid overlaying my Android Mapbox mapView? I was unable to find answer to this in Mapbox API documentation. Thanks for any help.

[image: This is how the map renders on my Android device]

XML of the view:

```
<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        mapbox:mapid="@string/map_id"
        mapbox:accessToken="@string/mapbox_token"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mapView.getMapOverlay().setDrawLoadingTile(false);
```

should help. See [TilesOverlay class](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-android-sdk/api/0.7.3/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/overlay/TilesOverlay.html#setDrawLoadingTile(boolean)).